# PHP continues loop inside loop

Tags: php

I have a repeated row which have 5 columns. I want when every time row is looped column data is looped number but continues after every loop. Sample code:

```
$list = 0;
$list++;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ){
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">$list</div>
  <div class="col-2">$list</div>    
  <div class="col-2">$list</div>
  <div class="col-2">$list</div>
  <div class="col-2">$list</div>
</div>
}
```

Sample result what i want:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">1</div>
   <div class="col-2">2</div>
   ...
   <div class="col-2">5</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">6</div>
    <div class="col-2">7</div>
    ...
   <div class="col-2">10</div>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your sample code only outputs one row; do you have a current attempt that loops over some rows, so that you could show us the output of that?

Comment: And how many times do you want that to continue looping increasing the value of $list

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you fully, but maybe it's already sufficient to simply move `$list++` into the loop. Just replacing `<div>$list</div>` with <div>{$list++}</div>` might give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested loop to iterate through both your rows and columns while keeping a counter outside of the loop:

```
$counter = 1;
for ($rowCount = 1; $rowCount < 5; $rowCount++ ) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    for ($colCount = 1; $colCount < 5; $colCount++ ) {
        echo '<div class="col-2">', $counter, '</div>';
        $counter++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/rfnXa)

Answer (score 0):

Simply increment the counter `$list` as part of the output

```
<?php
$list = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ){

    echo "<div class='row'>
              <div class='col-2'>$list++</div>
              <div class='col-2'>$list++</div>    
              <div class='col-2'>$list++</div>
              <div class='col-2'>$list++</div>
              <div class='col-2'>$list++</div>
          </div>";
}
```

Using `$list++` it will output the current value and then increment it by one ready for the next line etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use two loops. One for how many rows($i) you have second one for iteration (1,2,3,4,5) ($list)

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$list = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ){
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    for ($list = 1; $list < 6 ; $list++) {
        echo "<div class='col-2'>$list</div>";
    }
echo "</div>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```